# How to increment global variable from function in python

Tags: python

I'm stuck by a simple increment function like

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

## setup parameters and state variables
T       = 1000                # total time to simulate (msec)
dt      = 1                   # simulation time step (msec)
time    = arange(0, T+dt, dt) # time array
Vr      = -70                 #reset
El      = -70                

## LIF properties
Vm      = zeros(len(time))      # potential (V) trace over time 
Rm      = 10                    # resistance (mOhm)
tau_m   = 10                    # time constant (msec)
Vth     = -40                   # spike threshold (V)

## Input stimulus
I       = 3.1                 # input current (nA)
Vm[0] = -70

Fr = 0

## iterate over each time step
def func(Ie, Vm, Fr):
    for i, t in enumerate(time):
        if i == 0:
            Vm[i] = -70
        else: 
            Vm[i] = Vm[i-1] + (El- Vm[i-1] + Ie*Rm) / tau_m * dt
            if Vm[i] >= Vth:
                Fr += 1
                Vm[i] = El
     return

Ie = 3.1
func( Ie, Vm, Fr)
print Fr

## plot membrane potential trace  
plot(time, Vm)
title('Leaky Integrate-and-Fire')
ylabel('Membrane Potential (mV)')
xlabel('Time (msec)')
ylim([-70,20])
show()
```

Why after the func is called, the Fr is still 0?

I know it's simple but I have wasted long time on this

Thank you

Comment: newbie myself, but shouldn't you return Fr in the function? Seems like the variable is local

Comment: @jonrsharpe it passed the condition but the value is not incremented

Comment: @jonrsharpe look at `func` definition :)

Comment: @Subbeh thanks, the problem is the variable is local in the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two Fr variables in different scopes

```
Fr = 0
```

Is outside of your function, thus never changed.

```
Fr += 1
```

Is inside a function and will be incremented, but this is a different variable.

Here is the solution (one of the possible ones):

```
def func(Ie, Vm, Fr):
    for i, t in enumerate(time):
        if i == 0:
            Vm[i] = -70
        else: 
            Vm[i] = Vm[i-1] + (El- Vm[i-1] + Ie*Rm) / tau_m * dt
            if Vm[i] >= Vth:
                Fr += 1
                Vm[i] = El
     return Fr
```

Then, just do

```
Fr = func(Ie, Vm, Fr)
```

One more tip.
If your `Fr` variable is always 0 by default you can do this:

```
def func(Ie, Vm, Fr=0):
```

when defining the function, and pass the third paramenter only when you need something different that 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify variable outside of the scope of the function you need to use the `global` keyword

```
my_var = True # Declare a variable on the global scope
def my_function():
     global my_var # tell the interpreter that you want to use the global "my_var"
     my_var = False # Change global my_var value

my_function() # call the function
print my_var # check result
```

Be advised however that it is not considered a good practice to do so.

You should try to isolate as much as you can the scopes in your code to make it more readable.

```
my_var = 3 # Declare a variable on the global scope
def my_function(my_var):
     return my_var + 1

my_var = my_function(my_var) # call the function and assign result to global variable
print my_var # check result
```

Comment: This is bad advice - `global` is rarely the correct solution.

Comment: Using global vars is not a good practive though. I think he'd better just return the final version of Fr. In outer words Fr = func(Ie, Vm, Fr)

Comment: Yes, the problem is the variable is locally computed in the function, thanks for help

Comment: I agree, but incrementing a variable out of the scope of a function is what the OP is asking :). This seems to be a simple script, i'm not sure it makes sense to speak about "best practices"

Comment: Well, I think speaking about "best practices" is always makes sense, especially when it comes to a someone new to programming :)